# Compare the data of a single field with all fields in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in Excel like below shown, here I am looking for duplicates identification or batch kind.

[image]

How do I identify this kind of data (in VB macro or another way)?

Comment: HI Alan,i have tried some basic things using Excel like concatenating the 2 cells and running count if and using sumproduct function in excel but in any extra or some part of info is missing in 1 or the other  field the above things are not working so i am looking for other ways to find the duplicates.

Comment: You're looking for a fuzzy match solution and there isn't going to be one that's exact and 100% accurate.  There is a good solution for this on communities.sas.com via friedegg, but with the new system I'm not sure how to find it, you may want to try searching on there.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Fuzzy-match-using-a-string-variable-between-two-large-datasets/m-p/208283/highlight/true#M51636

Answer (score -1):

here is some code that might be able to do what you want. Beware that the code is case sensetive. Hope that helps :)

```
Sub testDuplicate()
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
For j = 1 To lastrow
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If j = i Then
            'Do nothing
        ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) Then
          Cells(j, 2).Value = "Duplicate"
          Exit For
        Else
          Cells(j, 2) = "Unique"
     End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help.But in above example output s.no 11,13 are actually duplicates if we run this i think we cant able to identify those 2 and it returns as 2 unique records.i looking for a solution like if any extra or some part of info is missing also it should identify is there a way to identify these. please help me to identify a way to fix this kind of data.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to clean the data first. For example, Canadian Corps of Commissionaires has two ways that it is spelled. You might want to try creating a new column that is the first 2 or 3 words of the account name, and use an `upcase` or `lowcase` function to make it case-insensitive. Then you can easily find duplicates from the new column.

Since you tagged SAS, here is a possible SAS-based solution:

**Step 1: Get the first 2 words for each Account Name and make it case-insensitive**

```
data have2;
     length Account_Name2 $20.;
     set have;

     word_length = countw(Account_Name);
     if(word_length > 2) then Account_Name2 = upcase(catx(' ', scan(Account_Name, 1), scan(Account_Name, 2) ) );
         else Account_Name2 = upcase(Account_Name);

     drop word_length;
run;
```

**Step 2: Sort the data by `account_name2` and save duplicates to a new dataset**

```
proc sort data=have2
          out=_TMP_
          nodupkey
          dupout=dupes;
     by account_name2;
run;
```

Note that the `_TMP_` dataset is simply there to prevent overwriting the `have2` table.

**Step 3: Merge `dupout` into the cleaned table `have2` by `account_name2`, then flag duplicates**

```
proc sort data=have2;
     by account_name2;
run;

data want;
     merge have2
           dupes(in=duprecs keep=account_name2);
     by account_name2;

     Dupe_Flag = (duprecs);

     drop account_name2;
run;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Stu, i will try this.